# Why am I not getting any output(linear search)?

Tags: c++, output

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
int n;
int current_element;
cin>>n>>current_element;
int arr[n];
for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
    cin>>arr[i];
}
int i;
for(i=n-1;i<=0;--i){
    if(current_element==arr[i]){
        cout<<i;
    }
    else{
        cout<<"-1";
    }
}
}
```

I was trying to do linear search program but there was no output, what is wrong in the code?

Comment: maybe not the reason for no output, but this looks wrong `for(i=n-1;i<=0;--i)` that loop is either executed never or until `i` overflows

Comment: The program is ill-formed. The size of an array must be compile time constant in C++. Which `n` is not.

Comment: Typo or unclear understanding. The check `i<=0` needs to be `i >= 0`.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you declared " i " twice and that has no sense. Here is the right code:

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
int n, i=0;
int current_element;
cin>>n>>current_element;
int arr[n];
for(i=0;i<n;i++){
    cin>>arr[i];
}

for(i=n-1;i<=0;--i){
    if(current_element==arr[i]){
        cout<<i;
    }
    else{
        cout<<"-1";
    }
}
}
```

This way you initialize " i " once with the value of 0 and it should work.

Comment: that i got but, one test case is not working100 2
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99 100 _my output is_ -1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-12 how come?@Stefan

Comment: Poor suggestion regarding `i`. It is a loop variable and should be in the scope of the loop only. The real problem is that `i <= 0` is logically incorrect.

Comment: Yeah, it's true.  It should be " i>=0" and you should put i=0 before the second for.

Comment: What? That's not the case since 80s C. for loop is one own block, everything inside it is within a closure. There were some non-compliant compilers, e.g VC4.0 which didn't follow that or had it as an option.

Answer (score 0):

i think its because in your for loop you said

```
for(int i = n-1; i <= 0; --i)
```

this doesnt seem like what you are trying to do as it says that it will keep running as long as i<=0 however i is never less than or equal to zero. i think you would want to write i>=0 instead. also, you have 2 "i" variables which you initialized.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you made a mistake on the second loop clause.

- Your code

```
...
    //loop condition is causing the problem
    for(i=n-1;i<=0;--i){
...
```

- Fixed code

```
...
    //loop condition is causing the problem
    for(i=n-1;i>=0;--i){
...
```

The loop condition causes the program to not enter the second for loop. Modifying it makes the program work.

- Full code

```c
    #include<iostream>

    using namespace std;

    int main(){
    int n;
    int current_element;
    cin>>n>>current_element;
    int arr[n];
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        cin>>arr[i];
    }
    int i;
    //loop condition is causing the problem
    for(i=n-1;i>=0;--i){
        if(current_element==arr[i]){
            cout<<i;
        }
        else{
            cout<<"-1";
        }
    }
    }
```